# Debugging ASP.NET web service crash after looking for collection results

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

if I debug an ASP.NET web service and look for variables in visual studio 2012 all is well as long as I don't let visual studio enumerate a collection result. VS hangs a while, tells me that timeout has occured and after that if I try to step to next code line I get the crash dialog (VS want to debug w3wp.exe and has no right for that...).

Is this behaviour normal? Thanks for any help.

P.S. I run Visual Studio as Administrator while Debugging.

Comment: How are you getting the collection? DB query?

Comment: Enable tracing in the service and try to call it without debugging.

Comment: The collections are Dictionary<...> or SortedList<...>. Most collections are of system types, no classes. Filled (manually) from DB queries. And: The collections are sometimes very big (up to 200,000 elements). But the problem occurs with small collections too.